# Extracting from Files in Python

Tags: python

I have a `text file` and i am trying to add to `b` all the text until the word `Finish` shows up. However this just gives me an `infinte loop` How can i fix this

```
def  extract(filename):
b = ''
line = f.readline()
while line:
    line = f.readline().strip()
    while line != 'Finish':
        b = b + line
        line = f.readline()
print(b)
```

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: That `while` creates an infinite loop. Change it to `if`.

Comment: the word finish shows up a bunch of times so im trying to make it so all the text before the first one gets added

Comment: The problem is that unless the first line is `Finish`, that `while` loop never quits. Replace with an `if` as advised in another comment. You also need to `break` from the `for` loop when you do find a line that is equal to `Finish`: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: A cleaner way to do it is to change that `while` block to `if line == 'Finish': break`. Don't forget to de-dent the `b = b + line` to take it out of the `if` block. Even better: save the lines into a list and join them into a string at the end. That's assuming that you actually want one big string - a list of strings may be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

If the first `line` is not `'Finish'`, your code gets stuck in that `while` loop. Change the `while` to `if` to check if that `line` is `'Finish'`, then move on to the next line. When you hit a `'Finish'`, `break` out of the for loop or `return b`.

(Thanks to PM 2Ring)

Comment: In Python you _can_ iterate over the file object returned from `open`. Doing `for i in f:` iterates over the lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

a simple code without any imports:

**text file:**

```
something 1
something 2
something 3
Finish
something 4
something 5
something 6
```

**Code**

```
file = open('try_text.txt', "r")
b = ''
for line in file:
    if "Finish" in line:
        to_append = line.strip().split("Finish")
        b += to_append[0]
        break
    else:
        b += line
print b
```

**output:**

```
something 1
something 2
something 3
```

Comment: hey can you look at my updated attempt, and see if there is a way to fix that   thanks, i feel like a slight adjustment would make that infinite loop not occur

Comment: no thats great thanks, im just supposed to use two while loops. One that checks the whole file and one that checks until finish shows up

Answer (score -1):

You can use `itertools.takewhile` which will continue until either the end or file or until its criteria is met, eg:

```
from itertools import takewhile

with open(filename) as fin:
    lines = (line.strip() for line in fin)
    b = ''.join(takewhile(lambda L: L != 'Finish', lines))
```

Which for a file of:

```
something 1
something 2
something 3
Finish
something 4
something 5
something 6
```

Gives you `b` as:

```
something 1something 2something 3
```